# Stop NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest from caching responses

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, objective-c-blocks

I call

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
```

with a request that has *cachePolicy* set to *NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData*

Does this call cache the response? If so, how do I ensure that it won't? I realize it will not retrieve anything from a cache, but I want to make sure it doesn't leave anything around either. I couldn't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test shows that it seems to cache the result as normal.

The way to avoid caching entirely is to implement a [NSURLConnectionDataDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) delegate, returning `nil` from [connection:willCacheResponse:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate/connection:willCacheResponse:) and instead use
[[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/connectionWithRequest:delegate:) to send the request using the delegate.

To test for yourself if it caches, you can try the above way of disabling caching and setting a breakpoint in `connection:willCacheReponse:` and see if it's called. If it's called, the request would normally have been cached.

Comment: How do I do a delegate with the block based API?

Comment: Looks like I need to switch to using - (id)initWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id < NSURLConnectionDelegate >)delegate

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/briancollins/BCURLConnection which implemented the async call for iOS 4, but it's useful to adapt it for my needs.